# Регулярное выражение для получения параметров url

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть строка '/abc/x=1+2&y=25&c=1', где 'x=1+2&y=25&c=1' является определенным набором фильтров. Я хочу написать функцию, которая бы с помощью регулярки доставала значения каждого фильтра, т.е.:

```
1) getSubString(str, 'x') - должна вернуть '1+2'
2) getSubstring(str, 'y') - должна вернуть '25'
3) getSubstring(str, 'c') - должна вернуть '1'
```

Моя функция пока что выглядит так:

```
const getSubString = (pathname, filterName) => {
  const regexp = new RegExp(`${filterName}=(.*)&`);

  return pathname.match(regexp)[1];
}
```

Не понимаю 2 момента:

1. В первом случая мне возвращается '1+2&y=25', то есть почему то поиск идет до последнего символа & в строке. Как сделать, чтобы движок искал с переданного мной 'x' до первого появления &?
2. В 3ем случае движок не находит никаких совпадений, т.к. в регулярке указан последним символом &. Как обработать такой кейс, когда возможно окончания на & или конец строки? Я пробовал заканчивать регулярку на (&|\z) - не получилось.

Comment: Может, легче использовать [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/URL/URL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В выражении `(.*)&` первый шаблон захватывает 0 и более символов, отличных от перевода строки, до *последнего* вхождения символа `&`.

В данном случае требуется найти текст до первого (ближайшего) вхождения символа `&` *или до конца строки*:

```
(.*?)(?:&|$)
(.*?)(?=&|$)
([^&]*)
```

Из трёх перечисленных выше шаблонов `([^&]*)` является самым быстрым, он же также находит переводы строк.
Используйте

```js
const getSubString = (pathname, filterName) => {
  const regexp = new RegExp(`${filterName}=([^&]*)`);
  const res = pathname.match(regexp)
  return res ? res[1] : undefined;
}

const text = '/abc/x=1+2&y=25&c=1';
console.log(getSubString(text, 'x'));
console.log(getSubString(text, 'y'));
console.log(getSubString(text, 'c'));
```

Чтобы совпадение происходило только после `/`, `?` или `&`, измените регулярное выражение на

```js
new RegExp(`[/?&]${filterName}=([^&]*)`);
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/W0QuH6/1/).

Comment: Спасибо, работает.